# QEMU won't boot anything on GPU passthrough VM

Tags: bash, 17.10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have been attempting to setup a Windows 7 VM with GPU passthrough on Ubuntu 17.10 and have not had any success getting anything to boot, from hard drives, to ISOs, to even actual DVDs. I get the same result every time, QEMU telling telling me there are no bootable devices.

Here is my executable for the VM:

```
 #!/bin/bash

vmname="windows7vm"

if ps -A | grep -q $vmname; then
echo "$vmname is already running." &
exit 1

else

# use pulseaudio
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa
export QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=8192
export QEMU_AUDIO_TIMER_PERIOD=99
export QEMU_PA_SERVER=/run/user/1000/pulse/native

cp /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd /tmp/my_vars.fd

qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name $vmname,process=$vmname \
-machine type=pc,accel=kvm \
-cpu host \
-smp 3,sockets=1,cores=3,threads=1
-m size=4G \
-mem-path /run/hugepages/kvm \
-mem-prealloc \
-balloon none \
-rtc clock=host,base=localtime \
-vga none \
-nographic \
-serial none \
-parallel none \
-soundhw hda \
-usb -usbdevice host:1532:0214 -usbdevice host:1532:0043 \
-device vfio-pci,host=04:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=04:00.1 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/tmp/my_vars.fd \
-boot order=dc \
-drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,file=/dev/sdb
-drive file=/home/keith/WIN_VM/win7install.iso,index=1,media=cdrom \
-drive file=/home/keith/WIN_VM/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso,index=2,media=cdrom \

exit 0
fi
```

QEMU basically tells me

```
Boot failed: could not read the boot disk
Booting from DVD/CD...
Boot failed: Could not read from CDROM (code 0003)
```

and later:

```
No bootable device.
```

As well as the aforementioned issues, when I close the QEMU window, I am greeted with

```
unknown keycodes `(unnamed)', please report to qemu-devel@nongnu.org
./WIN_VM/win7vm.sh: line 24: -m: command not found
./WIN_VM/win7vm.sh: line 41: -drive: command not found
```

in the terminal. I am relatively new to most of this virtualization stuff, however I am pretty familiar with linux. Any possible solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lengthy `qemu` invocation is missing some line-continuation backslashes, so the complete command doesn't get run.

The `\` (backslash) which appears at the end of some lines indicates that the command continues on the next line. When a line appears without the `\` at the end, it indicates the end of the command, and the next line is treated as a separate command.

Thus it is that on lines 24 and 41, bash is trying to interpret `-m` and `-drive` as commands, respectively, because the *previous* lines are missing the `\` to indicate the command continues.

I think you will find that your VM boots after you insert these backslashes.

---

P.S. Consider using libvirt with virt-manager (or GNOME Boxes) to create your virtual machines in the fuuture, as these are generally a lot easier to manage. In this case libvirt will manage the qemu configuration for you, depending on the options you set up for each machine in virt-manager.